# Converting number to binary

Tags: c

I'm converting a decimal to binary in a special form, but when I'm trying to store the binary generated  in an array bits which is 8 in size after i finish if i do print out it prints garbage after the no of bits which is leading to lots of problem in function binary to decimal which expects input to be of type char array of 1's and 0's.
problem 
1 why it prints the wrong size
2 why it displays the garbage
3 why out displays only initialized bits

The input to the value is 4

```
void toGolomb(int value) {
  char out[20];
  char bits[8];
  int count=0,num=0, output;
  while(value>0) {
    int remainder=value%2;
    out[count]=(char)(((int)'0')+remainder);
    value=value/2;
    count++;
  }
  int amount=count-1;
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<=amount;i++) {
    bits[num]=(char) '1';
    num++;
  }
  if(amount>=0) {
    out[amount]='0';
    for(i=amount;i>=0;i--){
      bits[num]=(char) out[i];
      num++;
    }
  } else {
    bits[num]=(char) '1';
    num++;
  }
  if(comflag==0) {
    int a =strlen(bits);
    printf(" length is %d \n",a);
    printf("%s\n",bits);
    output=  binary_decimal(bits);
    fputc(output,stdout);
  }
}
```

Output :

```
length is 17

111000c�����>�
205
```

Comment: where is ***binary_decimal()***? `char bits[8];`. Isn't 8 a bit too small?

Comment: Did you forget 0-termination? Also, avoid casts: Only use them where neccessary.

Comment: @Deduplicator originally there were no casts i just put it so that i m sure its not wrong how do i do 0-termination

Comment: @UmNyobe i need eight bits max and even if i make it 20 its still gives the error

Comment: @hsdhillon use `char bits[9];`. After binarl_decimal force null termination : `bits[8]=0;`

Comment: ok thanks sorry i know the description is not very clear but it seems there is something wrong in this code which i m missing and is there any other way you can suggest to extract the 1's and zero's

Comment: Alas, that is the *wrong* question for SO: "too broad". There are *many* good ways to do this, from quick-and-dirty to bomb-proof, using anything from standard string functions to bit sets, and loops or bit masks or `switch` cases. You should investigate at what point you run into trouble; use a debugger or pen and paper to trace what happens where and when.

Comment: @Jongware thxs for the input but a little code or an example would be perfect if you can

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_coding
char *toGolomb(int value){
    static const int m = 4, rbits_len = 2;//rbits_len = log 2 m
    static const char *rbits[] = {"00", "01", "10", "11"};
    char *bits;
    div_t x = div(value, m);
    bits = malloc(x.quot + 1 + rbits_len + 1);
    memset(bits, '0', x.quot);
    bits[x.quot] = '1';
    memcpy(bits + x.quot + 1, rbits[x.rem], rbits_len+1);
    return bits;
}

int main(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=10;++i){
        char *bits = toGolomb(i);
        printf("%d:%s\n", i, bits);
        free(bits);
    }
    return 0;
}
```